# Getting a "This question has been put on-hold since you loaded the page" popup when trying to flag my (closed) question on mobile

Tags: bug, closed-questions, flagging

My question was closed as off-topic, and it was suggested that Board & Card Games would be a better location. Okay; that works just as well. So I went to flag to request migration.

I was on mobile, so I opened up Chrome, opened the question, and tried to flag it. Except...

> [image: fully mobile web]

> This question has been put on-hold since you loaded the page - please refresh and try your action again.

Ooo...kay?

I decided to hit the "request desktop site" button and try like that. But... no dice.

> [image: "request desktop site"]

Same error.

I had reloaded the page, several times - so this error isn't very accurate.

I can flag it from my laptop, though:

> [image: flag as in need of mod attention]

This would seem to be a bug.

Comment: This *might* be a case for our friends over at http://shouldiblamecaching.com/